# Currency Symbol in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created two Magento Store Views in two Different Languages:

1. English
2. Dutch

English (EURO) Currency symbol comes in proper manner like € 20.00 but for Dutch Language view it shows me like 20,00 EUR. I wants to setup by default symbol € for both views since the EURO is the same. How can i achieve it in Magento.

Comment: if you choose euro for dutch currency then euro symbol is display by default

Comment: aaahhhh sorry its working after cleaning all cache!!!
but there is one problem money sperator is still showing ,[comma] instead of .[dot]

Comment: As per your updated comment try with my solution to change pattern will sure work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your locale setting

here is example for English. For that you have to do Minor changes in your Language File. Following is the Directory Structure of File.

```
=> root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)

=> around line 2611 you can see following code.
 <currencyFormat>
      <pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>
 </currencyFormat>

=> Now Change above code with Following code.

  <currencyFormat>
       <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)</pattern>
 </currencyFormat>
```

you can set it to for `Dutch`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define currency symbol from admin.

Go to `system->manage currency` and select `symbol`.

Here you can define currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

> **For both store english and dutch** select Default Config
>
> system > configuration > general > currency setup > currency options >

change Base currency = Euro

default display currency = Euro

Allowed Currencies = Euro and US DOllar

> ```
> only for dutch store admin-panel system > configuration
> ```
>
> > and select your dutch store.

After set your currency.

**system > configuration > general > currency setup > currency options**

```
Set this option
```

Default Display Currency = Euro

Allowed Currencies = Euro and US DOllar

Answer (score 1):

> You can change your locale setting
>
> here is example for English. For that you have to do Minor changes in your Language File. >Following is the Directory Structure of File.

```
>=> root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)
```

> => around line 2611 you can see following code.

```
> <currencyFormat>
>      <pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>
> </currencyFormat>
```

> => Now Change above code with Following code.

```
>  <currencyFormat>
>       <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)</pattern>
> </currencyFormat>
```

> you can set it to for Dutch.

---

To fix the comma form 1.000 to 1,000

add to the past post the following :

```
go to:  => root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/XX.xml (XX.xml For your Language)
```

for example : `=> root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)`

around line 2286 you can see following code :

```
<numbers>
    <defaultNumberingSystem> xxx your Language xxx </defaultNumberingSystem>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>,</decimal>
        <group>.</group>
```

to :

```
<numbers>
    <defaultNumberingSystem> xxx your Language xxx </defaultNumberingSystem>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
```

this wil change the comma form 1.000 to 1,000

Comment: This helped me the adjust mu currency symbols for both English and Arabic languages. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the file: `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml`

Go to the row that contains `<symbol>[Your currency]</symbol>` and change `[Your currency]`

Ex: change `<symbol>USD</symbol>` to `<symbol>XYZ</symbol>`