# Different pattern for different currencies

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, currency-formatting

I have two language shop (Polish and English) and I allow to pay in three different currencies. Problem is in display currency symbol. It's depend on language, not currency

Example:
(I choose currency Euro in English store view)

- Display: Euro 1
- Should display: 1 Euro

(In Polish shop currency= $, language = PL)

- Display: 100 $
- Should: $ 100

Where can I change it, to display symbol not as language "say" but as currency should look like?

P.S. I found something like that:
[Currency Symbol in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789871/currency-symbol-in-magento)
but this changed global pattern of currency, not specific one.

Answer (score 2):

[See this link](http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-change-currency-position-in-magento/)

```
1. Go from your root folder to /lib/Zend/Locale/Data
2. Find the lenguage file. In my case es.xml
3. Look for <currencyFormat>
```

[image]
**Before**

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
    <pattern>¤ #,##0.00</pattern>
  </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

**After**
[image]

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
    <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
  </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

Comment: I wrote that I did this. It's ok, but you show me how change place for every currency symbol, but for egzample Dollar and Euro should display in different place (dolar on the left side, euro - right side)

Comment: just change  ¤  icon position before and after where u want to display.

Comment: You don't understand. When I change this symbol position, all of currency show there (100$, 100 Euro, 100 Peso). I need to resolved this pattern (100 Euro, $ 100, 100 Peso).

Comment: admin panel system->manage currency->symbols there have to change name of currency.